# Reactjs : Error while creating component

Tags: reactjs, components

I am new to react, I need to create an infinite scroll page with dynamically loading divs. I have found a library online and I am using it here but I need the divs to be in a different component. I have been trying to do it but I am getting some errors. Can someone help me out, please?

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from "react-dom";
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-component';
import { Home } from "./components/Home";

class App extends React.Component{

    render() {

        return (

            <InfiniteScroll
                pullDownToRefresh
                pullDownToRefreshContent={
                    <h3 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>&#8595; Pull down to refresh</h3>
                }
                releaseToRefreshContent={
                    <h3 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>&#8593; Release to refresh</h3>
                }
                refreshFunction={this.refresh}
                next={this.generateDivs}
                hasMore={true}
                loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
                endMessage={
                    <p style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                        <b>Yay! You have seen it all</b>
                    </p>
                }>
                <Home/>
            </InfiniteScroll>
        );

    }
}

render(<App />, window.document.getElementById("app"));
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from "react";

const style = {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    fontSize: 40
};

const divs = [
    <div key={1} style={{ height: 200, background: '#9bc95b', ...style }}>Div no 1</div>,
    <div key={2} style={{ height: 200, background: '#ffd47b', ...style }}>Div no 2</div>,
    <div key={3} style={{ height: 200, background: '#95a9d6', ...style }}>Div no 3</div>,
    <div key={4} style={{ height: 200, background: '#ffa8e1', ...style }}>Div no 4</div>,
    <div key={5} style={{ height: 200, background: '#9bc95b', ...style }}>Div no 5</div>,
    <div key={6} style={{ height: 200, background: '#ffd47b', ...style }}>Div no 6</div>,
    <div key={7} style={{ height: 200, background: '#95a9d6', ...style }}>Div no 7</div>,
    <div key={8} style={{ height: 200, background: '#ffa8e1', ...style }}>Div no 8</div>,
];

const colors = ['#9bc95b', '#ffd47b', '#95a9d6', '#ffa8e1'];

export class Home extends React.Component{

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            divs: divs
        };
        this.generateDivs = this.generateDivs.bind(this);
        this.refresh = this.refresh.bind(this);
    }

    generateDivs() {
        let moreDivs = [];
        let count = this.state.divs.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            moreDivs.push(
                <div key={'div' + count++} style={{ height: 200, background: colors[i % 4], ...style }}>
                    Div no {count}
                </div>
            );
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ divs: this.state.divs.concat(moreDivs) });
        }, 500);
    }

    refresh() {
        this.setState({ divs: [] });
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({ divs });
        }, 3000);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            { this.state.divs }
        );
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something I notice immediately is how you are rendering the divs. Your return statement needs to return a single `div` tag and you are currently attempting to render an array of divs.

You didn't mention the error you are receieving, but I'm assuming that is the issue, then you can try the following:

```
render() {
    return (
       <div>
          { this.state.divs }
       </div>
    )
}
```

Also, a more effecient / cleaner way of doing this could be something similar to the following (since you are only changing the background color and keys for each div):

```
const divs = [
    '#9bc95b',
    '#ffd47b',
    '#95a9d6',
    '#ffa8e1',
    '#9bc95b',
    '#ffd47b',
    '#95a9d6',
    '#ffa8e1'
];

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {divs.map((bgColor, index) => {
          return <div key={index} style={{ height: 200, background: bgColor, ...style}}>Div no {index}</div>
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I did try it but I am still not able to access the functions generateDivs() and refresh() in index.js

Comment: Oh, gotcha. That is because you are defining them in Home.js and attempting to call them in index.js.

Comment: I know but if I am exporting them from Home.js and importing it in index.js then why can't I access them and how to do it?

Comment: You are exporting the component which allows you to use <Home /> like you are doing. In the way you have your code structured, you could just put the array in index.js and define the functions in that component since you don't even need to call / use the functions in Home.js

Comment: but what if I want some new components to have infinite scroll effect aswell?

Comment: If your going to be using it over and over, an option would be to create a Higher Order Component and just wrap any components that will use / need to use your infinite scroll component.

Comment: If you want to take the simple route, you could just import InfiniteScroll into Home.js then render your divs inside of that, then your functions you're trying to call will already exist in there.